# Replace nginx ingresses with API gateway ambassador

Tags: docker, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, ambassador

i am looking forward to replacing my Nginx ingress with ambassador API gateway with minimal changes is it possible ?

what is difference between Ambassador Edge Stack & Ambassador API gateway i have followed this document and found configuration AES in helm chart.

https://www.getambassador.io/docs/latest/topics/install/install-ambassador-oss/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible, sure.

According to [1] the difference between Ambassador Edge Stack & Ambassador API gateway is the number of features. Edge Stack seems to pack more features together. Check the link for details.

This should help too [2]

[1] https://www.getambassador.io/docs/latest/tutorials/getting-started/

[2] https://cloud.google.com/solutions/exposing-grpc-services-on-gke-using-envoy-proxy#alternative_ways_to_route_grpc_traffic

Answer (score 1):

Both NGINX ingress and Ambassador are [ingress controllers](https://www.getambassador.io/learn/kubernetes-glossary/ingress-controller/), and they support the Kubernetes ingress specification.

If you're only using the ingress specification, migrating is simple.

In practice, if you have a non-trivial application, you've likely used custom extensions to the ingress resource, which would need to be migrated. Ambassador uses the `Mapping` CRD which treats routes as independent objects.

As mentioned, Ambassador Edge Stack is a full superset of Ambassador API Gateway, with additional features. See